# What is this interface doing in this RecyclerView click listener?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I was following [this article](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/) to set a click listener on recyclerview, but I'm confused on what does the following interface does inside the `RecyclerItemClickListener`class:

```
  public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

Here is the complete class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        clickListener = listener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if(childView != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            clickListener.onItemClick(childView,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
}
```

This is how it's used on the Activity:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
        new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
);
```

It's working fine but I really want to know what is the responsibility of the interface or what it's doing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is in front of you, its a callback for RecyclerView item click.

Comment: @deepu513, would appreciate if you can give a deeper explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inner interface and inner classes are used when they make sense for example in here only class `RecyclerItemClickListener` uses interface `OnItemClickListener`so it makes sense it is inside class `RecyclerItemClickListener`.

So when you want to emphasizes that something makes no sense outside something you nest it or put it inside the class.

Notice how in your activity you call:  `new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener()` this part `new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener()`emphasized that it is an interface inside class  `RecyclerItemClickListener`, seems this interface doesn't make sense to be outside since it's not use by anything else so it is inside  `RecyclerItemClickListener` class.

Look this posts for more info: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648748/4031815), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850994/declaring-interface-inside-class-file-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688817/interface-inside-class)

Answer (score 1):

```
Hey if you see the constructor of the RecyclerItemClickListener class . the OnItemClickListener is initialized inside the constructor .

and  when we are calling the RecyclerItemClickListener. we are providing second argument for the initialization of the listener.


and inside the onInterceptTouchEvent method we are calling the onItemClick(View view,int position ) method of the listener by filling appropriate data .
```

you are sending reference  when you are calling the RecyclerItemClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how `interface` works you would understand it easily.
Since the `RecyclerView` doesn't have a click listener, this guy made his own class that is implementing `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`. So now when user touches the `RecyclerView item`, he catches the touch in code in `onInterceptTouchEvent`.

So now he comes to know that user clicked in item, so he makes an interface that is `OnItemClickListener` in the same class, and you are implementing that interface in your Activity class and you have to write the code that what happens after the click.

***But how is it fired when user clicks?***

You see the line

```
clickListener.onItemClick(childView,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
```

This line in turn calls your activity's onItemClickListener, so it call backs to your activity so you know that user has touched the item.

Hope you understood :)